# Solution of the recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How can we solve the following recurrence relation?

$$f_n=\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right )f_{n-1}-\frac{1}{a^4}f_{n-2} \\ f_0=1, f_{-1}=0$$

I calculated some values to see if there is a general pattern, but it doesn't seems so...

$$f_1=\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right ) \\ f_2 =\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right )^2-\frac{1}{a^4} \\ f_3 =\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right )^3-\frac{2}{a^4}\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right ) \\ f_4=\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right )^4-\frac{3}{a^4}\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right ) ^2+\frac{1}{a^8} \\ f_5=\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right )^5-\frac{4}{a^4}\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right ) ^3+\frac{3}{a^8}\left (\frac{2}{a^2}+b\right )$$

Have calculated these values right?

Is there an other way to find the solution of the recurrence relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence has the general form $f_n=cf_{n-1}+df_{n-2}$; the auxiliary equation is therefore $x^2-cx-d=0$, or in this case

$$x^2-\left(\frac2{a^2}+b\right)x+\frac1{a^4}=0\;.$$

This has roots

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\frac2{a^2}+b\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac2{a^2}+b\right)^2-\frac4{a^4}}}2&=\frac12\left(\frac{2+a^2b}{a^2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{4a^2b+a^4b^2}{a^4}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2a^2}\left(2+a^2b\pm|a|\sqrt{4b+a^2b^2}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Assuming that $4b+a^2b^2\ne 0$, these roots are distinct; call them $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Then the general solution is $f_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$, where $A$ and $B$ are chosen to satisfy the initial conditions. In particular, $A+B=1$, and $A\alpha+B\beta=f_1=\frac2{a^2}+b$. From these two equations one can solve for $A$ and $B$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Why is the auxiliary equation $x^2-cx-d=0$ ? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Mary: If you have a linear recurrence $f_n=a_1f_{n-1}+a_2f_{n-2}+\ldots+a_kf_{n-k}$, the associated auxiliary equation is by definition $$x^k=a_1x^{k-1}+a_2x^{k-2}+\ldots+a_k\;,$$ and there’s a general theory explaining how to use the roots of this polynomial to get the general solution to the recurrence. For the case $k=2$ the technique is described in detail in most elementary discrete mathematics texts, and many of them prove its correctness as well. [This PDF](http://delta.cs.cinvestav.mx/~debrup/ho1.pdf) discusses the method.

Comment: I see... I found that $$f_n=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}-\frac{\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}$$ I want to show that $f_n \neq 0$. To do this I did the following: So that we have $f_n=0$ it must stand that $$\frac{\alpha^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}=\frac{\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta} \Rightarrow \alpha^{n+1}=\beta^{n+1} \Rightarrow \alpha=\beta$$ which is a contradiction. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mary: I didn’t check your algebra, but if your closed form for $f_n$ is correct (and it looks very plausible), then so is your argument showing that $f_n\ne 0$ for $n\ge 0$. (Note that if $n=-1$, $\alpha^{n+1}=\alpha^0=1$ *is* equal to $\beta^{n+1}$, as it should be, since $f_{-1}=0$.)

Comment: @Mary: Actually, you do have to do a little more work. If $n+1$ is even, then you could have $\alpha^{n+1}=\beta^{n+1}$ with $\alpha=-\beta$. That would happen only if $2+a^2b=0$, so as long as you know that $a^2b\ne-2$, you can conclude that $f_n\ne 0$ for all $n\ge 0$.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: @Mary: You’re very welcome!